# How can I verify username or email are correct using Devise and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise and Rails 4.

I am working with login screen. In login screen i'm passing username/email and password but I have to check whether any one of the field username or email matched with any user in system.

Tried following condition to find user with username or email but it will be throwing an error for devise valid password method.

**Condition:**

```
user = User.where(["username = :value OR email = :value", { :value => username.downcase }])
```

after this i'm checking user password as like `user.valid_password?(password)`

> **Error:** NoMethodError (undefined method `valid_password?' for #)

For following condition valid_password? will be working fine

```
user = User.find_by(email: email.downcase)
```

But i have to check both username and password in `::find_by` method like as follows

```
user = User.find_by("email= email.downcase OR username= email.downcase")
```

Is there some way I can accomplish something like above?

Comment: if you're using devise, why are you manually searching for a user?  It does that for you.  If you want to verify that devise itself is working, the gem comes with it's own tests you can run.

Comment: you can use `before_action  :authenticate_user!` you don't need to check manually

Comment: do you you need to rewrite `User.find_by("email= email.downcase OR username= email.downcase")` to rails way?

Comment: Devise handle it using before_action :authenticate_user!. But how can we manually check in API in which data came from iOS APP?

Answer (score 0):

This is most wise confuse error, when an single instance is mixed up wish a relation, you simply forgot `#first` select from the relation, since `where` returns relation, rather than `find_by`, which returns a record for single match. So just rewrite (for rails 5):

```
user = User.where(email: email.downcase).or(username: email.downcase).first
```

and for Rails 4 with `arel`:

```
users = User.arel_table
user = User.where(users[:email].eq(downcase).or(users[:username].eq(email.downcase))).first
```

or with partially plain SQL:

```
user = User.where(["username = :value OR email = :value", { :value => username.downcase }]).first
```

Comment: partial plain SQL worked for me. added .first method. Thanks.